# Issue Deploying Sample WAR on Turnkey Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to learn how apache and tomcat and war files work

I have downloaded The Turnkey Tomcat on Apache VM and am running it in Parallels

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/tomcat-apache

I have downloaded a sample WAR file

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/

I then upload the sample.war file in the Tomcat Manager Application

[image: WAR deploy screenshot]

But when I browse to "http://[ip-address-of-vm]/sample" i get Not Found

[image: Not Found screenshot]

Comment: show logs: apache and catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add a `JkMount` directive to the Apache mod_jk configuration. Edit the file `/etc/tomcat6/mod_jk.conf` and add a line like this:

```
JkMount /sample* ajp13_worker
```

The `mod_jk.conf` file most likely already contains `JkMount` directives for the manager webapp and a few others. Make sure the name of the AJP worker (`ajp13_worker` in the example above) matches the one used in existing mappings.

Then restart the Apache Web server.

Comment: This worked, why is this not done when I "deploy" the WAR? Is there a configuration to make that happen? When I go to the web root I am directed automatically to the /cp path, how is that?

Comment: It it not done automatically when you deploy the war because with this setup, Apache Web Server is listening on port 80 and all http requests go to it first. This config tells it to forward some of the requests to Tomcat. As for the root redirect, it is probably caused by a redirect rule in the Apache config.